# Problem between Github Private project and Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, github, gitlab, devops

I have a Kubernetes and I deployed Jenkins in K8s.
I have a Private repo in GitHub.
I created credentials by ssh keys and I created credentials by Login/Password.
I installed a GitHub, Kubernetes plugins

So when I created freestile project on Jenkins and push button Build I evreytime saw a
 `ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.`

I don't know which the problem and how to resolve this.
Can somebody help me.

[image]

[image]

my jenkins2.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins2
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        ports:
          - name: http-port
            containerPort: 8080
          - name: jnlp-port
            containerPort: 50000
        volumeMounts:
          - name: jenkins-vol2
            mountPath: /var/jenkins_vol
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /home/administrator/.ssh/
            name: my-ssh-key
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-vol2
          emptyDir: {}
      volumes:
        - name: my-ssh-key
          secret:
            secretName: my-ssh-key
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank evreybody.
Problem with repository. I add origin repo in Jenkins and that issue is resolved.
[image]